# List Comprehension para esse caso

Tags: python, lista

Como posso usar *list comprehension* para esse caso:

```
>>> a = 'A'
>>> lista = [1, 2, 8, 5, 10]
>>> l = [a, num for num in lista if num%2 == 0]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    l = [a, num for num in lista if num%2 == 0]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Como podem ver essa sintaxe não é possível. Minha ideia era criar uma nova lista somente com os números pares de `lista` e com `a`.

```
['A', 2, 8, 10]
```

Como posso fazer isso com *list comprehension*?

Comment: Mas como assim? Você quer que `A` fique no  primeiro item da lista e em seguida os números pares?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não exatamente. A ordem não interessa, só quero adicionar `a` na lista.

Comment: talvez algo como: `l = [a] +  [num for num in lista if num%2 == 0] `?

Comment: @JJoao deu a resposta. Coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(como o @stderr simultanemante sugeriu), neste caso o mais simples é concatenar(ou seja `+`) o "a" à  lista em comprensão

```
novalista = [a] + [num for num in lista if num%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Para verificar se o item atual da iteração é um [inteiro](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), e um número par ou igual `a` faça:

```
l = [item for item in lista if type(item) is int and item % 2 == 0 or item == a]
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 2, 8, 5, 10, 'A', 'b', 12]
a = 'A'

print([item for item in lista if type(item) is int and item % 2 == 0 or item == a])
# [2, 8, 10, 'A', 12]
```

---

**Edição**: Se for uma lista que tenha somente números e você queira apenas adicionar `a`, como [sugerido pelo **JJoão**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153037/6454), concatene a variável como uma lista:

```
l = [item for item in lista if item % 2 == 0] + [a]
```

Além do [operador modulo `%`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), também pode-se usar o [bitwise `and`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), por exemplo: `item & 1 == 0`.

Comment: Estou começando a entender. Acho que ele quer botar o `A` primeiro, como se fosse um cabecalho.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Pelo que entendi ele quer uma nova lista com os números pares de `lista` e/ou também o valor de `a`.

Comment: @stderr no seu exemplo `lista` já contem o valor de `a` e se assim fosse eu não precisaria mais adicioná-lo.
O que eu quero é uma nova lista com os valores pares de `lista` e também adicionar o valor de `a`.
Eu poderia fazer isso:

`l = [num for num in lista if num%2 == 0]` e depois adicionar `a` com `l.append(a)`. Mas eu quero fazer isso com apenas uma linha de código.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva É só adicionar `a` na lista: `l = [item for item in lista if item % 2 == 0] + [a]`

Comment: Pois colocaram como comentário lá em cima. Alguém coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar.

Comment: Essas sobrecargas de operador que python tem ainda me espanta, rsrsrsrs.

Comment: @stderr, tivemos comentários simultaneos.. (paralelamente, gostei da tua reposta +1 pelo `is int`)